# PHP assign index of an array to another array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr1 = array('001','002','003');
$arr2 = array('aaa','bbb','ccc');

//$result = join $arr1 and $arr2;
```

I want `$result` such that `$arr1` value becomes index of `$result` and `$arr2` become value of each index of `$result`.  Final result should be

```
$result = array("001"=>"aaa","002"=>"bbb","003"=>"ccc");
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). Example:

```
array_combine($keys,$values)
```

for your question

try

```
$result = array_combine($arr1,$arr2);
```